# python, changing the permission of destination location during copy

Tags: python

```
print "copy ",meta_path + "/common/tools/meta to "+temp_dir+"/common/tools/meta"
shutil.copytree(meta_path + "/common/tools/meta", temp_dir+"/common/tools/meta")
```

this is python statement I use to copy a directory to different location, is there a way to copy paste with different permission during copy? I want to make the files in destination location with permission 777

```
        os.chmod(temp_dir, stat.S_IRWXU)
```

did not work reliably after the copying is done.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `chmod` line will only change the permissions of the directory itself, not everything in it. For that, you can iterate over `glob.glob(temp_dir + '/common/tools/meta/*')` or `os.listdir(temp_dir + '/common/tools/meta/*')`, calling `os.chmod` on each filename.
However, beware the dangers of making things world-writable/executable.